# Invalid identifier error in ORACLE SUBQUERY in select statement

Tags: oracle, subquery

Trying to execute following query, I'm facing invalid identifier  Exception.

QUERY:

```
SELECT bill_start_date                        AS "Bill Start Date", 
       bill_end_date                          AS "Bill End Date", 
       usage_category                         AS "Usage Category", 
       SUM(monthly_charges)                   AS "Monthly Rental Charges", 
       SUM(one_time_charges)                  AS "One Time Charges", 
       SUM(other_charges)                     AS "Other Charges", 
       SUM(no_of_users)                       AS Total_Number_of_Users, 
       SUM(monthly_charges + one_time_charges 
           + other_charges)                   AS "Total Revenue from the Users", 
       SUM(( monthly_charges + one_time_charges 
             + other_charges ) / no_of_users) AS "ARPU" 
FROM   (SELECT b.bill_start_date AS "Bill_Start_Date", 
               b.bill_end_date   AS "Bill_End_Date", 
               ( CASE 
                   WHEN bb.charge_type = '/item/cycle_forward' THEN 
                   'Monthly_Rental_Charges' 
                   WHEN bb.charge_type = '/item/purchase' THEN 
                   'One_Time_Charges' 
                   WHEN bb.charge_type LIKE '/item/%tax%' THEN 'Other_Charges' 
                   ELSE 'Unknown_Charges' 
                 END )           AS "Usage_Category", 
               SUM(CASE 
                     WHEN bb.charge_type = '/item/cycle_forward' THEN 
                     bb.amt_excl_tax 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)          AS "Monthly_Charges", 
               SUM(CASE 
                     WHEN bb.charge_type = '/item/purchase' THEN bb.amt_excl_tax 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)          AS "One_Time_Charges", 
               SUM(CASE 
                     WHEN bb.charge_type LIKE '/item/%tax%' THEN bb.amt_excl_tax 
                     ELSE 0 
                   END)          AS "Other_Charges", 
               Count(1)          AS "no_of_users", 
               bb.ban_id 
        FROM   tib_billsnap.bs_bill b, 
               tib_billsnap.bs_billlines bb 
        WHERE  b.ban_id = bb.ban_id 
        GROUP  BY b.bill_start_date, 
                  b.bill_end_date, 
                  bb.ban_id) ARPU 
GROUP  BY bill_start_date, 
          bill_end_date, 
          usage_category
```

ERROR:

```
ORA-00904: "USAGE_CATEGORY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 28 Column: 14
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no field by name `USAGE_CATEGORY`. Your `GROUP BY` and selection should have `"Usage Category"`, as you've aliased it that way

Answer (score 0):

In your subquery, you are creating a case sensitive identifier `"Usage_Category"`.  Creating case sensitive identifiers is generally a bad idea because it means that you would need to use case sensitive identifiers every time you reference the column.  In this case, you'd need to use the case sensitive identifier in both the `select` and in the `group by`.

```
SELECT ...
       "Usage_Category" as "Usage_Category",
       ...
  FROM (...) arpu
 GROUP BY ...
          "Usage_Category"
```

Of course, you'd need to do the same thing for all your case sensitive identifiers (`"Bill_Start_Date"`, `"Bill_End_Date"`, etc.).

Generally, the preferred approach would be to not create case-sensitive identifiers in the first place or to at least restrict them to the outer-most query if the front end application uses the case sensitive identifiers to produce the headers for a table.  In that case, your subquery would just have something like

```
            ( CASE 
               WHEN bb.charge_type = '/item/cycle_forward' THEN 
               'Monthly_Rental_Charges' 
               WHEN bb.charge_type = '/item/purchase' THEN 
               'One_Time_Charges' 
               WHEN bb.charge_type LIKE '/item/%tax%' THEN 'Other_Charges' 
               ELSE 'Unknown_Charges' 
             END )           AS Usage_Category
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. made necessary changes but now facing this.

Comment: @Varoo - Facing what?

Comment: Justin not able to post the updated query here.So posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery is missing the group by clause for the Usage_Category alias.
You should add bb.charge_type in the first (inner) group by:

```
group by b.bill_start_date, b.bill_end_date, bb.BAN_ID, bb.charge_type
```